# How to use a Linux container service with a windows server pipeline image

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a .NET Framework solution that builds a migration assembly file. Currently, it is building without any issues utilizing a Hosted agent using the `Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019` pool.

I also have a Linux container database using `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` base image.  On the pipeline, I was hoping to create a container service from my database that I could execute migrations against.  Eventually, I wanted this to be a build policy to prevent migrations from being added that would fail when migrated to an actual environment.

I'm starting to question whether this is a scenario that the service containers can handle. Unless I change the image to `ubuntu-latest`, the initialize container step that is created will fail because it can't run a Linux container on the windows image agent.

Is there a way I can structure the YAML such that I can run a Linux container service and interact with it from a Windows pool stage?

Here is a YAML example where the container service is created, but none of the existing build steps (removed from example) will execute because they depend on the windows server image.

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: local
    endpoint: acr-endpointexample
    ports:
    - 1433:1433
    image: example.azurecr.io/ci/database/mssql:latest
    options: -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e MSSQL_COLLATION="Latin1_General_BIN" -h localhost --name "local"

trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - feature/ado-host-agent-container-support

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

strategy: 
  matrix:
    Release:
      BuildConfiguration: 'Release'
  maxParallel: 2

services:
  database: local


steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true
  clean: true
  persistCredentials: true

- task: GitVersion@5
  displayName: Set version
  inputs:
    runtime: 'full'
    updateAssemblyInfo: true
    updateAssemblyInfoFilename: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SolutionAssemblyInfo.cs'
    additionalArguments: '/output buildserver'
    configFilePath: 'GitVersion.yml'
```

Comment: I am both trying to prevent having to convert to .NET Core and/or leverage a self-hosted agent if possible.

Comment: Spinning up Linux container on Windows pool and vice versa, is not, to my knowledge, possible. Spinning up a Linux container on self-hosted Windows agent probably would work. I gather that you are working with Azure DevOps Services, so would it be feasible to leverage Azure Container Instances for spinning up that mssql container? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/

Comment: Yeah, I had considered that as a possibility, but I'd expect to potentially get issues connecting to it from the Microsoft hosted agents without making it public (which I don't want to do).  Agree, the only alternative seems to be container-instance + scale-set-agents or self-hosting.